# Importing Large Data Files into pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas

I have a 1.5 GB .dat file that I need to import as a pandas dataframe, I'm running into memory issues (8GB RAM). How to I break the dat file into chunks to perform analysis?

Answer (score 1):

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', chunksize = x)
```

returns an iterator giving `x` lines from `file.csv` at a time.